# Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image heap

Tags: kotlin, gradle, quarkus, quarkus-native

I'm using a Quarkus-Kotlin-Gradle combo and I would like to build in native

I build the app with (native marked in the app.props: quarkus.package.type=native):

```
quarkus build
```

I got the following error:

> Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image
> heap.
>
> Error:
> com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException:
> Detected an instance of Random/SplittableRandom class in the image
> heap. Instances created during image generation have cached seed
> values and don't behave as expected.  To see how this object got
> instantiated use
> --trace-object-instantiation=java.security.SecureRandom. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a
> static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by
> using the option --initialize-at-run-time=. Or you can
> write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly from
> your main entry point.

I got this error because of the following codepart (If I remove this, the native build is successful):

```
org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder
    .create()
    .loadKeyMaterial(
        keyStore("path\\to\\key\\key.p12", password),
        password
    )
.loadTrustMaterial(null, TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
.build()
```

I was trying to solve this problems with this solutions but non of them was working, I still get the same error:

```
@RegisterForReflection(targets = [java.security.SecureRandom::class])
class SecureRandomReflection
```

And in app.props:

```
quarkus.native.additional-build-args=\
  --initialize-at-run-time=java.security.SecureRandom\
  --trace-object-instantiation=java.security.SecureRandom
```

Is it possible the a problem is that the SecureRandom init is in a dependency? Or any idea?